# Why does authenticating one web app cause the other to have to reauthenticate (SSO AzureAD DotnetCore)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I'm pretty new to how this should work, so bear with me...

**All I want is for when I login to webapp1, my webapp2 already sees I'm logged in and doesn't require me to login or re-authenticate. Should be simple, right?**

Stack/flow is :

- dotnet core
- C#
- Azure AD
- oidc

---

**To keep things simple, I created/registered my two webapps from within VS**

(i.e. VS registered a web app on AzureAD for me from within VS). Doing it this way, the apps get created within AzureAD with the appropriate redirect URIs as well as enabling ID Tokens for the auth endpoint. Magic.

[image: Creating dotnet core app from VS]

[image: Selected Auth Type MS Id Platform]

I did this for WebApplication1 and WebApplication2. This also automatically creates for me an `AzureAD` section specific to my two web apps registered in AzureAD.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "mydomainhere.onmicrosoft.com",
  "TenantId": "my-tenant-guid-here",
  "ClientId": "my-client-quid-here",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

All is great thus far.

When I startup webapplication1, it starts up and immediately asks for me to pick an account:
[image: Authenticate me]

Great, I select the appropriate account, grant consent, and then am taken to my webapplication1:

[image: WebApplication]

Now for brevity's sake, Imagine I do the exact same thing for WebApplication2. However, when I start it up, I'm again asked to pick an account and grant consent. I get that, I've never granted consent yet. So fine, after I've picked an account and granted consent I'm taken to my WebApplication2.

However, here's the rub. When I simply refresh my WebApplication1, that site now **again** asks for me to pick an account before allowing me to interact with the WebApplication1.

Why?? I want SSO to work. What am I missing here? I want for WebApplication1 and WebApplication2 to no longer require me to reauthenticate unless I sign out on one of those sites and/or the token expires. I don't get it.

Comment: Basically, when you signed in your web app with your account "wadeswlaker@gmail.com", then you open a new tab in the same browser to visit `portal.azure.com`, you should sign in successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... tiny? But that's not at all what I'm after. I want to sso between two sites registered in porta.azure.com. I don't care about sso'ing from site 1 to portal.

Comment: Yes... And I just want to inform you that it's similar.. I had 2 web app in my local side and both of them integrate Azure AD to let users sign in, and they used the same Azure AD app(had the same client id and tenant id). Then as you know when we open different solutions by VS, we need to open 2 VS, and whenever we start the app via VS, it will create a new instance of Chrome(I used Chrome as default), then upon running 2 apps, they will both redirect to sign in page. if I sign in one of the app in one of the Chrome instance, then copy another app's home page url in this instance,

Comment: then it won't ask me to sign in again but sign in automatically. so I say it's the similar with sign in azure portal... You may just try if you can sign in your app then open azure portal without signing again in the same browser instance.

Comment: The process of going through and registering your apps creates an Application in Azure (and a App Registration).  If you use the same settings (mainly client id) for both Apps I think it will work.  If they are different then they are two different Applications in Azure AD so cannot share the same signon and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The “choose an account” prompt can be bypassed by using OAuth parameters HSU=1 and Login_Hint parameters. Currently this only works with the v1 endpoint though and does not yet work with the v2 endpoint. The product team is working on a release for the v2 endpoint.

See: [Bypass Choose your account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/310175/bypass-the-azure-ad-sso-choose-an-account-prompt-a.html) and [Automatically select an account in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#automatically-select-account-on-azure-ad)

As for the SSO aspect, the user should remain signed into both apps if you have the applications configured correctly. Open ID Connect issues access tokens and refresh token to the users who haven authenticated to the app. If another app is accessed in the same browser, the user who is logged into the first application should automatically be logged in because the browser maintains the user's session. The session for that user will be maintained until either the browser is closed or the access token expires (after 1 hour by default).

Since it sounds like you are using the same tenant you will be able to stay signed into both apps needing to enter the credentials twice using the [OIDC sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC).

This is an old [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MohaxN6fsDs) my colleague and I made using the older OIDC Azure sample, but it shows the basic setup for how this works.

Here is a more recent [quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core) for achieving SSO.

Additional resources:
[Multiple Azure AD web apps Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/21766/multiple-azure-ad-web-apps-authentication.html)
[SSO to multiple sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/770888/can-i-use-azure-for-sso-to-multiple-websites.html)